# C#: Неправильная кодировка при скрытом консольном окне

Tags: c#

Есть WPF-приложение. К нему подключен класс `ConsoleWindow.cs` для отображения консольного окна приложения.

Иногда возникает необходимость выполнить процесс и вывести в окно приложения его `StandartOutput` или `StandartError`.

Делаю это так:

```cs
ProcessStartInfo process = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe", $"/c \"{command}\"");
process.CreateNoWindow = true;
process.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
process.RedirectStandardError = true;
Process proc = Process.Start(process);

string output = proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
string error = proc.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
```

Если в момент выполнения команды консольное окно отображено, то ошибка выполнения команды выводится в диалоговое окно корректно.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но если консоль скрыта, то выводится что-то такое:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

С чем это связано и как можно исправить? Я пробовал вручную устанавливать кодировку для ошибки и вывода, но это не помогло.

---

**`ConsoleWindow.cs`**:

```cs
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace TestWpfApp
{
    public class ConsoleWindow
    {
        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        static extern bool AllocConsole();

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        static extern IntPtr GetConsoleWindow();

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern bool ShowWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int nCmdShow);

        const int SW_HIDE = 0;
        const int SW_SHOW = 5;

        public static void ShowConsoleWindow()
        {
            var handle = GetConsoleWindow();

            if (handle == IntPtr.Zero)
                AllocConsole();
            else
                ShowWindow(handle, SW_SHOW);
        }

        public static void HideConsoleWindow()
        {
            var handle = GetConsoleWindow();
            ShowWindow(handle, SW_HIDE);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Видимо потому что до появления консоли она не знает, какая кодировка у нее и использует ANSI по умолчанию. Попробуйте это решение https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1216176/373567

Comment: Кстати, а зачем вам вообще окно консоли? Можно же обычный TextBox использовать :) https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1086544/373567

Comment: @aepot то есть мне по сути надо показать консоль на время выполнения команды, а потом снова скрыть?

Comment: Пробуйте, я не пробовал. 2 ссылки в комментах выше, могут помочь.

Comment: @aepot да, это помогло. Но если, предположим, у меня в приложении нет консольного окна вообще. Как тогда можно получить нормальный текст?

Comment: Вторая ссылка рассказывает, как. А так, просто запустить `Process` и прочитать с него вывод, безо всякой консоли.

Comment: @aepot но ведь в том-то и проблема, что при обычном чтении вывода от `Process` я получаю текст с неправильной кодировкой. Или я что-то неправильно понял?

Comment: Вы можете подклбючиться к двоичному источнику `.StandardOutput.BaseStream` например создав собственный `StreamReader` в нужной кодировкой. И из него уже читать. Для вычитывания вывода консоль не нужна.

Comment: @aepot ок, спасибо!