# Как сделать корректный вывод работы команды SSH?

Tags: c#, ssh

Работаю с такой штукой как ОВЕН ПЛК200, и смысл заключается в следующем:
Через форму подключаюсь по SSH, потом задаю команду и ответ вывожу на listbox, но результат мало того, что выводится одной строкой, так еще и выглядит как-то странно, примерно вот так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Помимо этого, результат выводится через раз, и только в режиме дебага, когда на каждую строчку поставлю точку останова, поэтому наверное надо это решать в помощью Thread.Sleep(), или можно как-то другими изменениями кода это поправить?
Вот код, который выполняет отправку команды и получение результата:

```
private void CommandSend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        StringBuilder ReadStream(StreamReader reader)
        {
            StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
            string line;
            while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                result.AppendLine(line);
            }
            return result;
        }
        if (SSHclient.IsConnected)
        {
            OVEN_info.Items.Clear();
            StringBuilder answer = null;
            SshCommand sc = SSHclient.CreateCommand(txtCommand.Text);
            ShellStream stream = SSHclient.CreateShellStream("stream", 0, 0, 0, 0, 1024);
            var reader = new StreamReader(stream);
            var writer = new StreamWriter(stream);
            writer.WriteLine(sc);
            answer = ReadStream(reader);
            OVEN_info.Items.Add(answer);
        }
    }
```

Библиотека, с которой работаю - SSH.NET

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A3%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8_ANSI

Comment: это VT100 коды, их можно либо в консоль вывести, включив поддержку, либо вырезать.

Comment: @aepot, А как можно включить их поддержку?

Comment: я под прошлым вопросом вам ссылку давал, там показано, а что за приложение у вас - понятия не имею, но наверное не консольное, тогда нужно быдет [руками саму консоль включать](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1216176/373567).

Comment: А вот я хотел бы спросить момент один:
Вот я анализировал ваш пример и там в строчке using ShellStream s = client.CreateShellStream есть параметр "xterm", вот что он означает и поможет ли его изменение как-то решить мою проблему?

Comment: чтобы узнать, надо попробовать, но проще использовать настоящую консоль для вывода, там все консольные штуки VT100 будут поддерживаться